# HTML To picture using html2canvas

Tags: javascript, php, html, canvas, html2canvas

I'm trying to convert HTML to picture using html2canvas. The problem is that arabic characters didn't convert correctly !

```
</html>
<body dir="rtl">
    <a class="STO_one" href="#">
        <span><b> بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم </b> </span>
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/html2canvas.js"></script>
    <script>
        html2canvas(document.body, {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what's your actual output?

Comment: http://i59.tinypic.com/2rp3685.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arabic Encoding with html2canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459072/arabic-encoding-with-html2canvas)

Answer (score 1):

if you do not have following attribute in the style sheet it will not work with you "text-align: right;" it **MUST** be right.

For Ex. `<span><b style="text-align: right"> بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم </b> </span>`

Comment: Thank you so much, I've been searching for a solution for a week now!, I want to say that this will not work if you have `letterRendering:true`, remove it and this will work :D

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding `letterRendering:true` in your code as follow

```
<script>
            html2canvas(document.body, {
                onrendered: function(canvas) {
                    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
                },
              letterRendering:true
            });
    </script>
```