# Html2canvas image capturing issue with UTF-8 characters

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, utf-8

I want to capture my webpage, In order to this I find html2canvas, when I use as shown below ,my UTF-8 (persian) characters get in trouble and this direction destroyed as you see.

HTML:

```
   <div id="wrapper">
        <span>این کاراکتر ها بهم میریزند</span>
    </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    html2canvas($("#wrapper"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;

            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                saveAs(blob, "Dashboard.png");
            });
        }
    });     
});
```

WebPage:

[image]

Captured WebPage via html2canvas:

[image]

you can see full example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vahid_krgr/bn4j2a29/1/)

What is wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the box css that have trouble to :

```
text-align: left; //or right or justify
```

that work for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bug with html2canvas ([Arabic Encoding with html2canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15459072/arabic-encoding-with-html2canvas)) and can be fixed by setting `text-align: left` on your wrapper element.

Here's an updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ydeL72m8/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot. i was about to ask the same question on malayalam language. You saved my project

Answer (score 2):

Just replace this line to new edited line

```
return styles.letterSpacing !== 0 ? toCodePoints(value).map(function (i) { return fromCodePoint(i); }) : breakWords(value, styles);
```

new line instead

```
return [value];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the sentence in the html2canvas.js file

```
textList = (!options.letterRendering && /^(left|right|justify|auto)$/.test(textAlign) && noLetterSpacing(getCSS(el, "letterSpacing"))) ? textNode.nodeValue.split(/(\b| )/) : textNode.nodeValue.split("");
```

use:

```
textList = (!options.letterRendering && /^(left|right|justify|auto|center)$/.test(textAlign) && noLetterSpacing(getCSS(el, "letterSpacing"))) ? textNode.nodeValue.split(/(\b| )/) : textNode.nodeValue.split("");
```

Answer (score 1):

you must to use last version library html2canvas this reslove your problem;

Answer (score 1):

Add this styling to the wrapper object:

```
letter-spacing: normal !important;
```

source : [Arabic font rendering](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/948)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same messy Arabic letters with only <h1.. h6> elements, I solved it by using styled p [Paragraph] elements instead.
[image: Arabic headers problem]